# Spring Integration graph editor tab in Spring Tool Suite loses "manual-mode" edits when edit raw XML source

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-integration, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, spring-tool-suite

I'm currently using Spring Tool Suite (STS) (Version: 3.6.4.201412021321-CI-B775, Build Id: 201411281415, Platform: Eclipse Luna SR1 (4.4.1)) with Spring Integration 4.1.0.

I have a Spring configuration XML file that includes the Spring Integration namespace.  I have a large workflow that is difficult to get to layout nicely on the integration-graph with "automatic layout" mode.  As such I did the following:

- Went into the integration-graph tab and used "manual layout" mode to
  organize my graph then I saved that layout.
- Went back to the "source" tab and added some components to the XML
  file and saved the file.
- Upon returning to the integration-graph tab the "manual layout" is
  still selected (as it was when I last left that screen) but my
  original "manual layout" mode changes are no longer saved.
- Returning to "automatic layout" mode then switching back to "manual
  layout" mode doesn't seem to help.  The issue also happens even if
  you just change a space or delete/re-add a character to the raw XML
  file (basically if the XML file is modified at all).

To reproduce use this XML context.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

    <int:inbound-channel-adapter id="fileAdapter" ref="fileReadingMessageSource" method="receive" auto-startup="true" channel="files">
        <int:poller fixed-delay="#{T(java.lang.Integer).MAX_VALUE}" />
    </int:inbound-channel-adapter>
    <bean id="fileReadingMessageSource" class="org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource">
        <property name="directory" value="C:/Users/af25830/Desktop/tmg-exchange-gateway-nam/t2" />
    </bean>
    <int:channel id="files" />
    <int:logging-channel-adapter id="logger" level="INFO" logger-name="fileLogger" channel="files" auto-startup="false" />
</beans>
```

- Initially graph looks like this:
  [image]
  `.settings/com.springsource.sts.config.flow.prefs` contains:

  ```
  //com.springsource.sts.config.flow.coordinates\:http\://www.springframework.org/schema/integration\:/spring-integration-test/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/integration/spring-integration-test-context.xml=<?xml version\="1.0" encoding\="UTF-8"?>\r\n<graph>\r\n<element clazz\="InboundChannelAdapterModelElement" type\="inbound-channel-adapter">\r\n<structure end\="1038" endstart\="1008" start\="809" startend\="939"/>\r\n<bounds height\="118" width\="120" x\="19" y\="17"/>\r\n</element>\r\n<element clazz\="ChannelModelElement" type\="channel">\r\n<structure end\="1280" endstart\="1280" start\="1254" startend\="1280"/>\r\n<bounds height\="118" width\="120" x\="159" y\="17"/>\r\n</element>\r\n<element clazz\="LoggingChannelAdapterModelElement" type\="logging-channel-adapter">\r\n<structure end\="1401" endstart\="1401" start\="1283" startend\="1401"/>\r\n<bounds height\="118" width\="120" x\="299" y\="17"/>\r\n</element>\r\n</graph>
  ```
- Enter "manual layout" and move something to get it to look similar to this:
  [image]
  `.settings/com.springsource.sts.config.flow.prefs` contains:

  ```
  //com.springsource.sts.config.flow.coordinates\:http\://www.springframework.org/schema/integration\:/spring-integration-test/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/integration/spring-integration-test-context.xml=<?xml version\="1.0" encoding\="UTF-8"?>\r\n<graph>\r\n<element clazz\="InboundChannelAdapterModelElement" type\="inbound-channel-adapter">\r\n<structure end\="1038" endstart\="1008" start\="809" startend\="939"/>\r\n<bounds height\="118" width\="120" x\="19" y\="17"/>\r\n</element>\r\n<element clazz\="ChannelModelElement" type\="channel">\r\n<structure end\="1280" endstart\="1280" start\="1254" startend\="1280"/>\r\n<bounds height\="118" width\="120" x\="159" y\="17"/>\r\n</element>\r\n<element clazz\="LoggingChannelAdapterModelElement" type\="logging-channel-adapter">\r\n<structure end\="1401" endstart\="1401" start\="1283" startend\="1401"/>\r\n<bounds height\="118" width\="120" x\="337" y\="148"/>\r\n</element>\r\n</graph>
  ```
- Go to the "source" tab and make any change (delete a char and re-add it).  Save file.
  `.settings/com.springsource.sts.config.flow.prefs` contains:

  ```
  //com.springsource.sts.config.flow.coordinates\:http\://www.springframework.org/schema/integration\:/spring-integration-test/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/integration/spring-integration-test-context.xml=<?xml version\="1.0" encoding\="UTF-8"?>\r\n<graph>\r\n<element clazz\="InboundChannelAdapterModelElement" type\="inbound-channel-adapter">\r\n<structure end\="1038" endstart\="1008" start\="809" startend\="939"/>\r\n<bounds height\="118" width\="120" x\="19" y\="17"/>\r\n</element>\r\n<element clazz\="ChannelModelElement" type\="channel">\r\n<structure end\="1280" endstart\="1280" start\="1254" startend\="1280"/>\r\n<bounds height\="118" width\="120" x\="159" y\="17"/>\r\n</element>\r\n<element clazz\="LoggingChannelAdapterModelElement" type\="logging-channel-adapter">\r\n<structure end\="1401" endstart\="1401" start\="1283" startend\="1401"/>\r\n<bounds height\="118" width\="120" x\="299" y\="17"/>\r\n</element>\r\n</graph>
  ```
- Return to integration-graph tab and go to "manual layout" mode, you'll see your changes are now reverted.

This is very commonly done and as-such it would be nice if "manual layout" edits didn't get reverted whenever the raw XML file gets edited.

Am I missing a step that would prevent that from happening?

Comment: Cool that you discovered this. I was unaware of the switch to manual layout. It stores coordinates in the project preferences (.settings folder of the project).It seems to be working for me though... Changes in raw XML doesn't affect the manual layout.

Comment: Looks like you've hit some sort of a bug. Does the manual layout remain on the diagram if you restart STS? Check if under .settings folder in yoyr project you have the com.springsource.sts.config.flow.prefs file and it has coordinates in XML format there. Note that auto-layout setting is a global preference affecting all "bean config" diagrams.

Comment: I've confirmed the layout remains if you exit/restart STS.  The underlying com.springsource.sts.config.flow.prefs file ends up getting edits made to it if the XML source gets touched, which basically then seems to clobber any manual edits you made.  I've updated my question with examples and diagrams.

Comment: Tony, think it's best if we move all this discussion into a JIRA issue. I've troed to do my best moving your instructions to reproduce the issue into JIRA. Here it is: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3992 I'm still unable to get the manual layout to be switched off but I'll give it another try a bit later. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Alex you saved me a bit of work.  Appreciate it.

Comment: Hi guys, could you please tell me how can you toggle the graph from "automatic" to "manual" mode? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, got it... Is a tiny icon buried with 100 more icons in the top bar... Sorry for the noise:)